# Create polygon from a raster in specific areas

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python

I have a raster with buildings that look darker.
I want to detect the dark areas and enclose them with a polygon

[image]

this is what i want to achieve, or something similar.
[image]

What tools could I use with QGIS, ArcGIS, or Python to achieve this?

Comment: First you have to choose a platform and make an attempt. Since there's already a QGIS Answer, you should probably choose QGIS for this Question.

Answer (score 1):

This amounts to translating the values ​​contained in the pixels to obtain a layer vectorized thematic information.
It is a work of classification. There are several methods.
You can do it with QGIS (for example after having installed for example the OTB toolbox libraries (to download here: [enter link description here](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/)
or the plug in QGIS, the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin (SCP) (to download here  : `[enter link description here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin)

There are tutorials : [enter link description here](https://briques-de-geomatique.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/classification-supervisee.html)